# express.js: jade view cant access function parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

Having this code:

```
router.get('/progress', function(req, res, next) {
    collection.findOne({id: req.query.id}, function(err, doc) {
        fdn = new Date(doc.nacimiento);
        res.render('progress');
    })
})
```

From my jade view, i cant access doc (a simple jason object) properties. I know i can do `res.render('progress', doc);`, and it works ok, but i want to understand why i cant access doc properties, as a res.local, like fdn (i can access fdn). Is not doc a local too ?

Comment: Your template is run in a different scope, it can't access variables in the scope where `res.render()` gets called.

Comment: API sais views access locals variables in something called res.locale. My view can access `fdn`

Comment: `res.locals` needs to be populated first (`res.locals.fdn = new Date(...)`). But it's better to pass them to `res.render()`: `res.render('progress', { fdn : new Date(...) })`.